# Agrupar objetos por uma determinada chave angular

Tags: ionic, angular, typescript

Tenho três objetos:

```
0{
  conta: "teste",
  data: "01/01/2018"
},
1{
  conta: "teste",
  data: "01/03/2018"
}
2{
  conta: "teste2",
  data: "02/02/2019"
}
```

Preciso agrupar os objetos que tiverem a conta com o mesmo nome, resultando assim:

```
0{
  conta: "teste"{
   0   {
     data:01/01/2018
    },
   1{
     data:01/03/2018
    }
}
1{
conta: "teste2" {
    0{
       data: "02/02/2019"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

da pra fazer com [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
let entrada = [
    {
        conta: "teste1",
        data: "01/01/2018"
    },
    {
        conta: "teste1",
        data: "01/03/2018"
    },
    {
        conta: "teste2",
        data: "02/02/2019"
    }
];

let saida = entrada.reduce((retorno, dados) => { 
    retorno[dados.conta] = retorno[dados.conta] || []; 
    retorno[dados.conta].push({ data: dados.data });
    return retorno; 
}, {});


console.log ( saida );
```

ou com [Array.foreach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
let entrada = [
    {
        conta: "teste1",
        data: "01/01/2018"
    },
    {
        conta: "teste1",
        data: "01/03/2018"
    },
    {
        conta: "teste2",
        data: "02/02/2019"
    }
];

let grupo = {};

entrada.forEach( ( valor ) => {
    grupo[valor.conta] = grupo[valor.conta]  || [];
    grupo[valor.conta].push({ data : valor.data });
});

console.log ( grupo );
```

Comment: Dessa maneira não obtenho o objeto da maneira que eu espero.

Como eu espero:
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]

Como eu tenho através dessa função:
{nomeConta1: Array(2),nomeConta2: Array(1)}

Comment: Dessa maneira eu não consigo iterar através de um ngfor, porque eu teria que especificar de qual conta eu quero fazer o loop, e como esse dado varia, não tem como eu setar fixadamente. Ex: *ngFor="let pergunta of contas.teste1"

Comment: entendi, é que sua pergunta foi “como agrupar os dados do objeto”, vou tentar ajustar